# strange compile error occured when using Generics in child class

Tags: java, generics, language-lawyer

Below is a code example, which causes a compile error.

```
    class A<T extends Number> {
        T a;

        T getA() {
            return a;
        }
    }

    class B<U> extends A<Integer> {
        public void test() {
            Integer i = getA();//fine
            B b = new B();
            Integer i1 = b.getA(); //Ooop !! has an error!!!
            Number i2=b.getA(); //fine
        }
    }
```

If I remove the `<U>` generic symbol or use `B<?> b = new B();`, then it compiles well.
Is the code above violating any java specification.

Comment: `B b = new B();` <--- Raw types here

Comment: @Sweeper why does  raw type  of `b` affects the `getA()` behavior, which has no ambiguity in the context?

Comment: @Sweeper the linkage you provide does not solve my question.

Comment: Did you _read_ it? Especially the "What's so special about raw types?" section.

Comment: @Sweeper Yes, but  still not getting understood. Can you explain why `Integer i = getA();` and `Number i2=b.getA();` behaves well in the context?

Comment: @Sweeper Thanks, I think I finally  got the point.